# Table in table pdfmake

Tags: javascript, css, pdfmake

http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

if in cell I put table, then 'text:3' in 3rd row inserted to 2nd column
if in cell I put text, then 'text:3' in 3rd row inserted to 3rd column so it should be.

Why I can't put table in cell of table and set rowSpan.
Sorry for my english language.

```
var dd = { content: [
 {
  table: {
   body: [
    [{text:'11111'},{text:'222222'},{text:'333333'}], //row1
    [                                                   //row2
     {ul: ['item 1','item 2']},
     { 
      // text:'22'
      table: {
       body: [['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'],['1', '2', '3'],['1', '2', '3']]
      }
      ,rowSpan:2
     },
     {text: "123123123"}
    ],
    [{text:'1'},{text:'2'},{text:'3'}]        
   ]
  },
 },
]}
```

try uncomment text:'22' and comment table in same cell

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. I hope it helps!

```
var dd = {
    content: [
        {
            table: {
                body: [
                    [{text:'11111'},{text:'222222'},{text:'333333'}], //row1
                    [                                                   //row2
                        {ul: ['item 1','item 2']},
                        // updated here !
                        [
                            '22',
                            {
                                table: {
                                    body: [
                                           ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'],
                                           ['1', '2', '3'],
                                           ['1', '2', '3']]
                                },
                                rowSpan:2
                            }
                        ],
                        {text: "123123123"}
                    ],
                    [{text:'1'},{text:'2'},{text:'3'}]
                    ]                
            },
        },
    ]
}
```